# Переопределение verbose_name для админки

Tags: django

Всем привет!

Пытаюсь кастомизировать админку джанго, вывел туда список пользователей. В таблице отображаю first_name и last_name:

```
list_display = ('first_name', 'last_name')
```

Но так как User - это не моя модель, а так сказать, встроенная, то я не могу задать либо переопределить verbose_name для них.

Пробовал это делать в конструкторе:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    User.first_name.verbose_name = 'my_title_in_admin'
    super(User, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Но ничего не поменялось. Пробовал так же в конструкторе ModelAdmin, но так же не вышло

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А можно поинтересоваться, на что и зачем вы хотите это поменять?

Comment: @andreymal, "Имя" и "Фамилия"

Comment: Просто включите русский язык в настройках джанги, и оно поменяется само

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возможное решение:

```
list_display = ['first_name_display', 'last_name_display']

def first_name_display(self, obj):
    return obj.first_name

first_name_display.short_description = 'my_title_in_admin'

def last_name_display(self, obj):
    return obj.last_name

last_name_display.short_description = 'my_title_in_admin'
```